# 10 inch Tablet is loading values from wrong dimens folder

Tags: android

today first time I am facing very awkward problem. I am building an android application that has cell phone and tablet version. For this I am providing multiple dimens folder. But the problem is Android 10 inch tablet is loading values from dimens folder that is cell phone version. And it is confirmed that tablet is loading values from cell phone version of dimensions. I have no idea why that is happening. For reference I am attaching the image as well. Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What is the resolution of the tablet?

Comment: Width in px ==> 1920 height in px 1116